# "b'ile over" seemingly incorrect spelling?

Tags: meaning, eye-dialect

> "There's no pleasin' her, nohow, no matter how you try! I wouldn't stay if 'twa'n't
>   for the wages and the folks at home what's needin' 'em. But some
>   day--some day I shall jest **b'ile** over; and when I do, of course it'll be
>   good-by Nancy for me. It will, it will."

Can you guess what *b'ile over* means above?

Incorrect colloquial spelling, I guess.

It's part of *Pollyanna* by Ms. Eleanor Porter.

Comment: The clue is in the _pleasin'_ and _'twa'n't_ etc. This is [an attempt to show] dialect. _b'ile_ is boil: the apostrophe signals the missing 'o', but there is no way to show that the 'e' is non-standard nowadays.

Comment: It's intended to show that the word _boil_ was at that time and place pronounced similar to _bile_.

Answer (score 1):

As Edwin Ashworth and Colin Fine indicate in comments above, *b'ile* is spelled as it is to convey two ideas: (1) that a letter (namely, an *o*) is missing between the *b* and the *i*, an omission marked by the apostrophe; and (2) that the word is supposed to be pronounced so as to rhyme with *vile*, *while*, and *Emerald Isle*, a hint conveyed by the addition of a silent *e* to a word that normally is spelled without an *e*. The word thus altered represents *boil*.

Dialect approximations sometimes take this approach, with mixed results, as your own experience shows. But now you'll be ready if you ever come across a sentence that says

> I t'iled in the s'ile with a c'ile of f'ile, while near me a pot o' b'ilin' 'ile r'iled.